# Failed to run my android application because a level 21 app generate level 23 files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

Here my build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.github.codechimp-org.apprater:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-android.jar')
}
```

I can compile my source code without problem but get the following error message when I try to run:

> /Users/myname/Projects/myproject/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v23/values-v23.xml
>
> Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. Error:(34)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'. Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':project:processReleaseResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Users/myname/.android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

I really don't understand. My compiledSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 21 and I even don't have a file called values-v23. Why got this error? Can anybody help? Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

@Gabriele Mariotti's answer solved this problem. But here comes another problem.

Error:Execution failed for task '::transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/org.brickred/socialauth/pom.properties
>       File1: /Users/xxxxxx/libs/socialauth-4.2.jar
>       File2: /Users/xxxxxx/libs/socialauth-4.2.jar

What could be the reason? I checkd there is of course only one socialauth-4.2.jar in my libs folder.

Comment: try remove folder `values-v23` from `res` folder in your app project

Comment: Don't have this folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

you are using the latest versions which has a dependency with **support libraries v24**.

**You have to use** `compileSdkVersion 24`

In general it is **not a good idea** to use this kind of dependencies (`+`) because you will not be able to reproduce the build in the future (since the dependencies will change)

Comment: Alternatively, the OP can specify a version to use for these libraries which is compatible with API 21.

Comment: It fixed my problem. But here comes another problem. Please refer to my Edit 1. Thanks.

Comment: @ZhouHao You should add in the `build.gradle` something like: `packagingOptions { 
         exclude 'META-INF/.../pom.properties'
         exclude '...'
     }`

Answer (score 0):

You have a resource file which is specifically targeted to API 23. You can either remove this file or change `compileSdkVersion` to 23. The later is preferable since your app will still be able to run on devices with versions of Android prior to level 23.